# Drop Down List Validation in Excel Cell inside a userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am displaying Excel inside a VBA form as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406319/display-a-part-of-an-excel-sheet-on-a-userform-using-vba/17407415#17407415).

[image]

I need to show a validation drop down list in the **Excel present inside the VBA form** as below

[image]

I tried below code. It is showing **compilation error**. **The same code works in a normal Excel window.**

```
With Me.Spreadsheet1.Range("A1").Validation
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
xlBetween, Formula1:=ValidationList
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
.InputTitle = ""
.ErrorTitle = ""
.InputMessage = ""
.ErrorMessage = ""
.ShowInput = True
.ShowError = True
End With
```

below is the error.
[image]

Comment: The OWC spreadsheet component might look like an Excel sheet, and it shares many of the same properties and methods, but it's not a fully-functional Excel worksheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams is right. If you type DOT after `Spreadsheet1.Range("A1")`, you will see that `Validation` is not present in the intellisense dropdown :) Interesting [READ](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/07/19/office-web-components-owc-part-iii-spreadsheet-control/) for you :)

Comment: Yes, the [Spreadsheet object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa205671(v=office.11).aspx) indicates that it is a very limited version of Excel.

Comment: I think a workaround would be to add a separate `combobox` to your userform, and after the `combobox` *click event* fires up to update the range to be displayed on the `spreadsheet control`. May not be that efficient but worth giving a try

Comment: @mehow : will macros work inside web office components ? I mean can we have macros enable in the excel sheet present inside the vba form ?

Comment: @logan youre walking on a thin ice. Do your research!